# Is it possible to use "Custom Sources and Sinks" to write/append file during Dataflow pipeline execution?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

My program relies on local system storage to write a file that is being generated by the program itself. Hence executing the job in "DirectPipelineRunner" mode. Below is the flow,

1. One of my function - Makes multiple REST API requests and creates/appends to a file(Output.txt) in local system storage.
2. **Pipeline**: **a)** Upload generated file to GCS **2)** Read the file from GCS **c)** Perform transformation **d)** Write to BigQuery.

Since, my program writes/appends API response to local system storage, I'm executing the pipeline in *DirectPipelineRunner* mode.

Is it possible to have temporary space in cloud to remove dependency on local file system So that I can execute the pipleline in *DataflowPipelineRunner* mode?

I guess [Custom Sources and Sinks](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/custom-io) can be used here. Can someone add some light on this problem statement?

Comment: Why can't you write to GCS directly?

Comment: Is it possible to append the file residing in GCS?

Comment: @Verti, it's not possible to append to a file in GCS. See this Stack Overflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20876780/how-to-append-write-to-google-cloud-storage-file-from-app-engine.

Comment: Do you really need appending? You can stream data into a file with Dataflow. You can also write to and read from multiple files on GCS with apache beams built in [WriteToText](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#file-based-input-and-output-data).

Comment: @Robbe Yes. I can consider streaming with Dataflow but I would like to process in batch mode. How about using Custom Sources and Sinks?

Comment: Why do you need to write to the local file? There's likely a way to accomplish the same without doing that.

Comment: @jkff I write to local file because my code will make more than 100 REST API request in an iterative manner and writes the parsed output to local file. Also, I want to achieve - "Write all or none". Moreover, streaming inserts are expensive.

Comment: Any reason why you can't just write a ParDo that performs your iterative REST calls and returns the results as a List? I'm not sure I understand why it has to be in a file. I'm not sure about the concern about streaming inserts too: you're saying you're using batch runner, so BigQueryIO.write() will use BigQuery load job API anyway; and BigQuery load jobs are atomic ("all or none").

Comment: Even if you're writing a streaming job, it's still possible to get BigQueryIO to use load jobs instead of streaming inserts - use .withTriggeringFrequency().

Comment: @jkff Thanks for adding some light here. I will try these and update.

Comment: @Vetri Did the comments solve your issue?

Comment: @Ggrimaldo yes. I removed the dependency on local storage by ingesting it directly to BigQuery.