# How to set the starting index for an ObjectWriteStream?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to build a connection to the file in a google storage bucket, but I have a difficulty to implement an `ObjectWriteStream`. The problem is that if I create an `ObjectWriteStream` to the file that is already on the cloud, it will delete the old file and start from the beginning of it. Here is an example code

```
namespace gcs = google::cloud::storage;
void test(gcs::Client client, string bucket_name, string file_name){
    auto writeCon = client.WriteObject(bucket_name.c_str(), file_name.c_str());
    writeCon << "This is a test";
    writeCon.Close();
}
```

What should I do to prevent the `ObjectWriteStream` from deleting my file and upload data from the location I want(e.g. append data to the file)? I have tried to call the standard ostream function `seekp` to set the stream location. This would not work since `ObjectWriteStream` does not support it. Strangely `ObjectReadStream` does not support this operation neither but it has an option `gcs::ReadRange(start, end)` to set the starting location. Therefore, I am wondering if there is a non-standard way to set the position for `ObjectWriteStream`. I will appreciate it if anyone can advise me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append write to google cloud storage file from app engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20876780/how-to-append-write-to-google-cloud-storage-file-from-app-engine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it will delete the old file and start from the beginning of it.

This is by design. Remember that *GCS is not a filesystem*. GCS is an object store. In an object store, the object is atomic unit. You cannot modify objects.

If you require filesystem semantics, you may want to use [Cloud Filestore](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/) instead.

Comment: I see the differences between the two products. Cloud Filestore fits what I need exactly, I appreciate your suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

The answers indicating that objects are immutable is correct. However, two or more objects *can* be concatenated together using the [compose](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/compose) API. Here's the [relevant javadoc](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/storage/Storage.Objects.Compose.html).

So you could combine a few techniques to effectively append to objects in GCS.

- You could copy your existing object (A) to a new object (B) in the same location and storage class (this will be very fast), delete A, upload new data into object C, and then compose B+C into A's original location. Then delete B and C. This will require a copy, delete, upload, compose, and then two deletes -- so six operations. Be mindful of [operations costs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing).
- You could simply upload a new object (B) and compose A+B into a new object, C, and record the name of the new object in a metadata database, if you're using one. This would require only an upload, compose, and two deletes.

Comment: The same API is also available in the [Google Cloud Storage C++ Client](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-cpp/0.8.0/storage/index.html) through the [ComposeObject()](https://googleapis.dev/cpp/google-cloud-storage/latest/classgoogle_1_1cloud_1_1storage_1_1v1_1_1Client.html#a41047d2e018b349cda5d3f9f32e43d24) Member Function.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very helpful. Cloud filestore might be a better solution as another answer said, but I appreciate your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Within Google Cloud Storage, objects are immutable.  See:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#immutability

What this means is that you simply *can't* append to a file.  You can re-write the file passing in the original content and then add more content.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I overlooked. I appreciate your information.